# Propose normal random variables using vdRngGaussian

Tags: mex, intel-mkl

I want to draw n random variables form the **Normal(mean, sigma2)** using the function **vdRngGaussian**.
One way to do this is with the command

```
vdRngGaussian(VSL_RNG_METHOD_GAUSSIAN_ICDF, stream, n, x, mean, sqrt(sigma2) )
```

Instead of this I want to use a for-loop. The mex-code I wrote is

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mkl.h>
#include "mkl_vml.h"
#include "mex.h"
#include "matrix.h"
#include "mkl_vsl.h"
#include <time.h>
#define SEED  time(NULL)

double normal(double mean, double sigma2, VSLStreamStatePtr stream);

/* main fucntion */
void mexFunction(int nlhs,  mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    double *x, mean, sigma2;

    VSLStreamStatePtr stream;
    vslNewStream( &stream, VSL_BRNG_MT19937, SEED );

    /* make pointers to input data */
    mean = (double)mxGetScalar(prhs[0]);
    sigma2= (double)mxGetScalar(prhs[1]);

    /* make pointers to output data */
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, mxREAL);
    x = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);


    x[0] = normal( mean, sigma2, stream);


    /* Deleting the stream */
    vslDeleteStream( &stream );

    return;
}

double normal(double mean, double sigma2, VSLStreamStatePtr stream)
{
    double x[1];

    vdRngGaussian(VSL_RNG_METHOD_GAUSSIAN_ICDF, stream, 1, x, mean, sqrt(sigma2) );

    return(x[0]);
}
```

When I run the code with the command

```
for i=1:5
out(i) = normalc(0.0, 1.0);
end
```

I get the following results:

```
-1.1739   -1.1739   -1.1739   -1.1739   -1.1739
```

If I call my function 5 times without a for-loop I get these results

```
-0.2720, 2.1457, -1.2397, 0.7501, 0.1490
```

Could you please help me.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stream you are creating with [vslNewStream](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/521853) takes a seed (the initial condition of the random number generator) as an argument, and you are basing this on [the output](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time_t/) of the [`time` function from the C time library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time/).  The problem is it returns a number of **seconds**.  This is resolution too coarse, and you end up with the same seed when you call it in a for loop.  (Assuming the for loop executes quickly and you are lucky with the start time.)

Perhaps use a different seed, like the [`high_resolution_clock` from the C++11 `<chrono>` header](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/high_resolution_clock/).  You may still get the epoch time, but in different units:

```
using namespace std::chrono;
system_clock::time_point now = high_resolution_clock::now();
system_clock::duration epoch = now.time_since_epoch();

long long ns = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(epoch).count();
long long mic = duration_cast<microseconds>(epoch).count();
long long ms = duration_cast<milliseconds>(epoch).count();
```

[Demo (cpp.sh)](http://cpp.sh/5pxw).

Alternatively, you can use elapsed CPU clocks from [MKL's `mkl_get_cpu_clocks` function](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/522131), but this goes back to zero when you shutdown your machine.  **Or just the [time in seconds as a `double` with MKL's `dsecnd`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/522130).**

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried to use  "the high_resolution_clock " as you proposed but when I run the code I get this message:  "error: identifier "using" is undefined   using namespace std; ". I tried to add libraries in order to fix it but I had no luck. I read function "dscend" and it sais that  returns time in seconds between two calls of the function (if I understood correctly). Could  you please tell me with more details how to use this in order to define a new seed? I am sorry, maybe this question is quite silly but I am new to C. Thank you very much.

Comment: @F.F. That means your not compiling as C++ or your compiler doesn't support C++11 or you haven't enabled C++11 support.  Can you give compiler details?  You didn't tag the question as any language.  For `dsecnd`, it's normally used for timing, but it returns an absolute time that can probably be of use (multiply by 1e7 or so and round/truncate to the required integral type).

Comment: Hello @chappjc. I had some unexpected problems and I couldn't see yor message earlier. I saved my code with the extension .cpp and it worked. Thank you very much.